# Angular2: OpaqueToken not resolved on lazy loaded module

Tags: angular

All code in this post is on [this github repository](https://github.com/jeusdi/issueAngular). In order to test it perform `npm start` and visit `http://localhost:3002`.

I've created a library where I declare several services like:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
    protected basePath = 'http://localhost/commty/cmng';

    constructor(@Optional()@Inject(BASE_PATH) basePath: string) {
        if (basePath) {
            this.basePath = basePath;
        }
    }
}
```

On this library, I'm using an `OpakeToken` in order to get `UsersService`'s `basePath` constructor parameter. This parameter is defined on `variables.ts` as:

```
export const BASE_PATH = new OpaqueToken('basePath');
```

On this library, I've created a module called `ApiModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [],
  exports:      [],
  providers:    [ PlansService, UsersService ]
})
export class ApiModule {}
```

I've published this library and it's used as an straightforward npm dependency package on my `webapp`: `"@living/cest": "0.1.0-unstable0028"`.

**On my `webapp`**, I've created an `environtment.ts` file in order to set this `OpaqueToken`:

```
ENV_PROVIDERS = [
  { provide: BASE_PATH, useValue: 'http://localhost:8082/commty/cmng' }
];
```

I'm using `ngrx` in order to create my internal behavior using a reflux model. I've created three modules: `AppModule`, `CoreModule` and `SharedModule`:

```
import { ENV_PROVIDERS } from './environment';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, ErrorComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    SharedModule, <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [
    ENV_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

So, I'm setting `ENV_PROVIDERS` (`BASE_PATH` opaque token provider) in `AppModule`, and I'm importing `CoreMoudle` and `SharedModule`.

I'm using `UsersService` inside all my `@Effect`s:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserEffects {
  constructor(
    private _actions$: Actions,
    private _store$: Store<IStore>,
    private _userService: UsersService,
  ) { }

  @Effect({ dispatch: true }) userLogin$: Observable<Action> = this._actions$
    .ofType('USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN')
    .switchMap((action: Action) =>
      this._userService.checkPasswd(action.payload.username, action.payload.password)
        .map((user: any) => {
          return { type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS', payload: user };
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          return Observable.of({
            type: 'USER_REDUCER_USER_LOGIN_ERROR',
            payload: { error: err }
          });
        })
    );
}
```

Each `@Effect` is bootstraped on `CoreModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ApiModule,
    StoreModule.provideStore(getRootReducer),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentOnlyWithExtension(),
    EffectsModule.runAfterBootstrap(UserEffects)
  ],
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

As you can see, I'm importing `ApiModule` once in `CoreModule`. This `CoreModule` is imported once in `AppModule`.

By other hand `SharedModule` stands for providing `ngrx` functionality to all components of `webapp`:

```
export const modules = [
  StoreModule,
  StoreDevtoolsModule
];

export const declarations = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: modules,
  exports: [...modules, ...declarations],
  declarations
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

I'm really check everything out, but `UsersService`'s `basePath` constrcutor parameter is not resolved to my url, it's always `null`.

I've took a look on debugger in order to find out what's wrong. Up to now I've been able to see that angular is trying to resolve `UsersEffect`'s `_userService` constructor parameter injectable. This code is reached:

```
Object.defineProperty(AppModuleInjector.prototype, '_UserEffects_77', { get: function() {
  var self = this;
  if ((self.__UserEffects_77 == null)) { (self.__UserEffects_77 = new jit_UserEffects63(self._Actions_60,self._Store_62,<b>self._UsersService_47</b>)); }
  return self.__UserEffects_77;
}});
```

Also, this code is generated but never reached:

```
Object.defineProperty(AppModuleInjector.prototype, '_Token_basePath_81', { get: function() {
  var self = this;
  if ((self.__Token_basePath_81 == null)) { (self.__Token_basePath_81 = 'http://localhost:8082/commty/cmng'); }
  return self.__Token_basePath_81;
}});
```

`LoginModule` is lazily loaded using this router configuration:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [{
   path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'
  }, {
    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => System.import('./login/login.module')
  }, {
    path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent
  }, {
    path: '**',    component: ErrorComponent
  }
];
```

`SharedModule` and `CoreModule` are eagerly loaded.

I hope I've explained so well.

**EDIT**

I've also tried to remove `CoreMoudule` and `SharedModule` and import everything on `AppModule`. Nevertheless, `BASE_PATH` opaque token keeps faling to resolve any value:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [ App ],
  declarations: [
    App,
    ErrorComponent
  ],
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    ApiModule,
    StoreModule.provideStore(getRootReducer),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrumentOnlyWithExtension(),
    EffectsModule.runAfterBootstrap(UserEffects),
    //CoreModule,
    //StoreModule,
    //StoreDevtoolsModule
    //SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [ // expose our Services and Providers into Angular's dependency injection
    ENV_PROVIDERS,
    APP_PROVIDERS
  ]
})
export class AppModule {
```